# Processing cost of making a new reference to an already-created object?

Tags: java, memory, reference

I'm making a game where I need to tell how many cars are contacting the player's car, and which cars. My plan is to create a `List`, and add and remove cars when necessary.

Here's my question.  My `Car` class is very expensive to create (processing power wise). How expensive is it to create a *reference* to a car? I know in C++ what I'm talking about is called a pointer. Here's an example in code:

```
Car newCar = new Car(); // expensive
Car carCopy = newCar.clone(); // expensive
Car referenceNewCar = newCar; // expensive?
```

`referenceNewCar` should point to the same place in memory as `newCar`, right? So it won't have to initialize anything, and saying `newCar.changeMemberVariableTo(1)` is the same as `referenceNewCar.changeMemberVariableTo(1)`; either way, `newCar` and `referenceNewCar` are both affected, because they point to the same place in memory.

I assume it would be cheaper to create a new reference than an entirely new `Car`. How much faster is it? If it takes, say, 3 seconds to create a new `Car`, will creating a new reference to the same car be nearly instantaneous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is instantaneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying a reference from one variable to another is *very* cheap. It's likely to be as cheap as copying an `int` or `long` value (depending on a few things about the JVM in question).

All you've got is two variables with exactly the same value - a reference. That value will be very small (4 or 8 bytes under most implementations) and copying it doesn't usually require any more effort than copying the bytes.

(I've a sneaking suspicion that *some* JVMs may be a little bit cleverer than this; for the sake of garbage collection, it's possible that some JVMs update flags about the oldest generation which has a reference to a particular object, for example - but that will vary by implementation, and my memory may be wrong anyway.)